# adding values in a row if duplicate value in another row in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame of two columns having word and frequency.

[image]

i want a new data frame when duplicate word comes the frequency should ad up as happened with word great

[image]

These seems to be pretty straight forward but i am not able to do it.
Any suggestion

Comment: share reproducible data not pictures.

Comment: @ Allan Indeed it helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` for this one:

```
library(dplyr)

word <- c("great", "good", "nice", "great")
freq <- c(2,4,5,6)
df <- data.frame(word = word, freq = as.numeric(freq)) 

df %>% group_by(word) %>%
  summarise(freq = sum(freq))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aggregate(dat$freq, by=list(dat$word), FUN=sum)
```